# External service configuration in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to use imports in services.yaml to move some services definitions to separate file. [Here you can find this in symfony doc.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/import.html)

But when i'm trying to do this I'm getting an error:

> Cannot autowire service "App\Domain\Test\Test": argument "$param" of method "__construct()" must have a type-hint or be given a value explicitly.

Here are my config files:

```
# services.yaml
imports:
    - { resource: services/test.yaml }

services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      
        autoconfigure: true 
        public: false       

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

And

```
# test.yaml
parameters:
    param: 'some param'

services:
    App\Domain\Test\Test:
        public: true
        autowire: true
        arguments:
            $param: '%param%'
```

Here is the service:

```
namespace App\Domain\Test;

class Test
{
    private $mailer;
    private $param;

    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer, string $param)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->param = $param;
    }
}
```

This is working well if I move parameters and service into services.yaml.
Do somebody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The _defaults section needs to be repeated in all your services file.  Also, config/services_test.yaml will automatically be loaded while testing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your first file try to load as service your service and can't fill automatically the parameter `string $param`.

A good fix may be to exclude your service:

```
services:
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php,Domain/Test.php}'
```

Another solution is to simply put this definition inside the `services.yaml` file.

You may also consider to load `App\Something\:` instead of the complete namespace but this has drawbacks if you try to autowire in cross-namespaces definitions. (some features may not work as expected)