# How to inject RabbitMqBundle producer into service?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have a problem with injecting RabbitMq producer from [RabbitMqBundle](https://github.com/php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle) into my service.

Service:

```
namespace App\Service;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\ProducerInterface;

class RatingPositionRecalculateService
{

    protected $entityManager;

    protected $positionProducer;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, ProducerInterface $producer)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->positionProducer = $producer;
    }

    public function recalculate(Carbon $day)
    {
        // do stuff
    }

}
```

old_sound_rabbit_mq.yml:

```
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
    connections:
        default:
            url: ''

    producers:
        rating_position:
            connection:       default
            exchange_options: { name: 'rating_position', type: direct }

    consumers:
        rating_position:
            connection:       default
            exchange_options: {name: 'rating_position', type: direct}
            queue_options:    {name: 'rating_position'}
            callback:         rating_position_service
```

and I get:

```
Cannot autowire service "App\Service\RatingPositionRecalculateService": argument "$producer" of method "__construct()" references interface "OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\ProducerInterface" but no such service exists. You should maybe alias this interface to the existing "old_sound_rabbit_mq.rating_position_producer" service. Did you create a class that implements this interface?
```

I've tried wiring using services.yml:

```
rating_position_recalculate_service:
        class: App\Service\RatingPositionRecalculateService
        autowire: false
        arguments:
            $entityManager: '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
            $producer: '@old_sound_rabbit_mq.rating_position_producer'
```

but I still get the same exception.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you only have one producer, you can define an alias like this in your `services.yaml`:

```
OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\ProducerInterface: '@old_sound_rabbit_mq.rating_position_producer'
```

But i suggest you to create an empty class for your producer:

```
// src/Producer/RatingPositionProducer.php

<?php

namespace App\Producer;

class RatingPositionProducer extends \OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\Producer
{
}
```

Then, in your  `old_sound_rabbit_mq.yml` file:

```
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
    ...
    producers:
        rating_position:
           class: App\Producer\RatingPositionProducer
           ...
```

In your `services.yaml` file:

```
App\Producer\RatingPositionProducer: '@old_sound_rabbit_mq.rating_position_producer'
```

And finally, in your `RatingPositionRecalculateService` class

```
// src/Service/RatingPositionRecalculateService.php

namespace App\Service;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use App\Producer\RatingPositionProducer;

class RatingPositionRecalculateService
{
    ...

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, RatingPositionProducer $producer)
    {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I went with second approach as I will have more then one producer. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem is related to the bundle. Your service definition looks ok. They wrote it in [the documentation](https://github.com/php-amqplib/RabbitMqBundle#usage):

> Here we configure the connection service and the message endpoints that our application will have. In this example your service container will contain the service old_sound_rabbit_mq.upload_picture_producer and old_sound_rabbit_mq.upload_picture_consumer. The later expects that there's a service called upload_picture_service.

Which means you should have a service `old_sound_rabbit_mq.rating_position_producer`. You can verify it by using the command `bin/console debug:cont --show-private | grep old_sound_rabbit_mq`.

**But the problem is probably somewhere else.**

Here is what I guess:

- You have a configuration file that registers all your classes as service
- You have another config file for your `RatingPositionRecalculateService`

If it's true, then the error is due to the duplicated registration of your service. While registering all the services, Symfony DIC tries to register your `RatingPositionRecalculateService` but can't link it to the producer (because the producer is not registered in the same file). You may have a look at another problem which has a similar issue: [External service configuration in Symfony 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782392/external-service-configuration-in-symfony-4/49782757#49782757)